# How to calculate SHA256 of large files in php

Tags: php, hash, sha256

I would like to calculate SHA256 of large files in PHP. Currently, I am using Amazon Glacier to store old files and their API to upload the archive. Initially, I just used small files that cannot reach to MB-sized images. When I tried to upload more than 1MB, the API response said that the checksum I gave to them is different from what they had calculated.

Here is my code to upload the file:

```
//get the sha256 using the file path
$image = //image path;
$sha256 = hash_file("sha256", $image);

$archive = $glacier->uploadArchive([
        'accountId' => '', 
        'body' => "",
        'checksum' => $sha256,
        'contentSHA256' => $sha256,
        'sourceFile' => $image,
        'vaultName' => 'my-vault'
    ]);
```

And the error:

`` AWS HTTP error: Client error: `POST https://glacier.us-west-2.amazonaws.com/vaults/70/archives` resulted in a `400 Bad Request` response:{"code":"InvalidParameterValueException","message":"Checksum mismatch: expected 9f1d4da29b6ec24abde48cb65cc32652ff589467 (truncated...) ``

I tried the function like below to check for the final hash but it seems it's not the right hash when I print it:

```
private function getFinalHash($file)
{
    $fp = fopen($file, "r");
    $ctx = hash_init('sha256');
    while (!feof($fp)) {
        $buffer = fgets($fp, 1024);
        hash_update($ctx, $buffer);
    }
    $hash = hash_final($ctx, true); print_r($hash);exit;
    fclose($fp);
}
```

The resulted hash is like this: ŸM¢›nÂJ½äŒ¶\Ã&RÿX”gíÖ'„IoA\C÷×
I presume that the only problem here is getting the final hash of the file. The file size is 5.7 MB.

I think there has something to with the correct way of providing the checksum but I don't know how I should do it with large files. I really need your help.

Comment: This not a cryptography question. You should ask this on stackoverflow.

Comment: Obviously, you are sending the checksum as raw bytes while the service expects you to send it as an hexadecimal-encoded string.

Comment: look at the second flag in hash_final. Set it to false for hex instead of raw output. http://php.net/manual/en/function.hash-final.php

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to calculate sha256 for large files in PHP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43039407/how-to-calculate-sha256-for-large-files-in-php)

Comment: What about just using `hash_update_stream()`instead of the while loop? http://php.net/manual/en/function.hash-update-stream.php

Answer (score 3):

Managed to get the desired output, and get the digest validated by the following routine.

```
<?php
    $fileName = isset($argv[1]) ? $argv[1] : die("Usage : php sha256.php <<filename>> <<hash>>" . PHP_EOL);
    if(!file_exists($fileName))
        die("FATAL : The file specified does not exists!");

    $hash = isset($argv[2]) ? $argv[2] : die("Usage : php sha256.php <<filename>> <<hash>>" . PHP_EOL);

    $ctx = hash_init('sha256');

    echo("INFO : Reading file $fileName ...");
    $file = fopen($fileName, 'r');
    while(!feof($file)){
        $buffer = fgets($file, 1024);
        hash_update($ctx, $buffer);
    }
    echo(" DONE!" . PHP_EOL);

    echo("INFO : Calculating SHA256 hash of $fileName ...");
    $hashRaw = hash_final($ctx, false); // Here, set the $raw_output to false
    echo(" DONE!" . PHP_EOL);

    echo ($hash . " INPUT " . PHP_EOL);
    echo ($hashRaw . " OUTPUT " . PHP_EOL);

    if($hash == $hashRaw)
        echo("INFO : Hash Comparison: OK!" . PHP_EOL);
    else
        echo("WARN : Hash Comparison: MISMATCH!" . PHP_EOL);
    echo("END" . PHP_EOL);
```

Your problem is, you are setting `$raw_output` to `true` in `string hash_final ( HashContext $context [, bool $raw_output = FALSE ] )`, which will generate the output as raw binary data. Either set it to false or don't use it at all, because it defaults to `false` ([see the doc](https://secure.php.net/manual/en/function.hash-final.php)). Hope this helps.